# How can I split out individual column values from each line in a text file?

Tags: java, parsing, text-parsing

I have lines in an ASCII text file that I need to parse.
The columns are separated by a variable number of spaces, for instance:

```
column1 column2     column3
```

How would i split this line to return an array of only the values?

thanks

Comment: the space between column1 and column2 is one, the spaces between column2 and column3 is five

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
String testvar = "Some   Data    separated  by     whitespace";
String[] vals = testvar.split("\\s+");
```

`\s` means a whitespace character, the `+` means 1 or more. `.split()` splits a string into parts divided by the specified delimiter (in this case 1 or more whitespace characters).

Comment: it doesn't compile, but .split("\\s+") does, i'll see if that works

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry - my bad on that one. ;) I'll tweak the answer for others.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/  */\n/g' < input
```

Two spaces there btw.

Answer (score 0):

Check the StringTokenizer class.