# Split String in Matrix or Tabular and stored into ArrayList

Tags: java, regex, arraylist, split, stringtokenizer

I want to perform split logic that convert single string into matrix or tabular form.
I have below string structure.

```
BlackPerl
Bill No: 101
Bill Date: 27/03/2015
Sr. Particulars     Qty   Rate     Amount
1   Knife           2     10.00    20.00
2   Pirates Cap     1     200.00   200.00
Total Amount 220.00
```

Sting structure is same every time but product should be variable(means product can be increased or decreased)

I am expecting the output like this

```
Sr. | Particulars | Qty | Rate   | Amount 
1   | Knife       | 2   | 10.00  | 20.00 
2   | Pirates Cap | 1   | 200.00 | 200.00
```

Means I need to store data in separate ArrayList like: 
Sr. ArrayList contain 1 and 2, Particulars ArrayList contain Knife and Pirates Cap and so on.

I have tried several things but not succeed 
first I thought I have to split string into tabular using this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22966659/split-string-into-columns-based-on-distance-between-values) 
then tried another [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413750/how-to-split-strings-into-columns), [Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236113/how-can-i-split-out-individual-column-values-from-each-line-in-a-text-file)

Can anyone please help me 
Thanks in Advance.

### Update 1

First I thought I need to split string using StringTokenizer so that I have tried

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(text, "\\s*[Sr.]+\\s*");
    while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
        Log.v(TAG, st.nextToken());
    }
```

Then again tried to split in using split
String lines[] = text.split("Sr.");

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < lines.length ; i++) {
    Log.v(TAG, "Line:: "+i+ " -- "+lines[i]);
    }
```

Comment: You might want to show some of the actual code you have written up until now

Comment: @dhke I am confused on this dont find any particular logic to perform task

Answer (score 0):

As you describe it, I would tackle it like this.

1. Take the part of your String between "Amount" and "Total". You can use String.indexOf()
2. Split this this into parts using line breaks
3. Split each of the parts into subparts using space signs
4. Since the second subpart may contain a space, merge the 2nd and 3rd if you have more than 5 subparts

Comment: thanks for your answer can you please provide some sudo code or some line of code.